# Name and derivation of the approximation $\frac{1+x}{1+y} - 1 \approx x-y$?

Tags: approximation

I am wondering if there is a name and way to derive the following approximation:

$$\frac{1+x}{1+y} - 1 \approx x-y$$

I'm essentially interested in how to refer to this.

Comment: What's wrong with calling it a "Taylor approximation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this a Taylor approximation. When $|y|\lt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1+x}{1+y}-1
&=-1+(1+x)\left(1-y+y^2-y^3+\dots\right)\\
&=x-y-xy+y^2+xy^2-y^3-xy^3+\dots\\[6pt]
&=x-y+O\!\left(\max(|x|,|y|)^2\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: i think there is a typo in the denominator of the LHS - should be 1+y, not 1-y?

Comment: Fixed it; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(1+x)}{(1+y)} - 1 = \frac{(1+x-1-y)}{(1+y)}  =\frac{(x-y)}{(1+y)}  \approx x-y$$

The approximation is valid when the value of $y$ can be neglected with respect to $1$